# Effective way to copy Suffix information between model clones in Pyomo

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pyomo

Imagine I have a `ConcreteModel` `m2` constructed using `m2 = m.clone()`. If `m2` has `Suffix` information on it such as `m2.ipopt_zL_out` that I would like to copy back over to `m`, what would be the most effective way to do so?

I could do something like `m.ipopt_zL_out[m.var] = m2.ipopt_zL_out[ComponentUID(m.var).find_component_on(m2)]`, but I have been told that `ComponentUID` can be expensive. Is this the recommended approach, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I typically do is create a forward and backward mapping from the ComponentUID string to the model component on each model. Creating a mapping for Pyomo objects is tricky and typically can not be done using the standard `dict` because things like Var are not hashable. There is a class called `ComponentMap` that you can use in place of a dictionary for this. There is also a helper function called `generate_cuid_names` that efficiently generates all of the CUID strings in bulk for a model and returns a `ComponentMap`.

Here is some example code:

```py
# m1 and m2 are ConcreteModels

from pyomo.core.base.block import generate_cuid_names

# generate forward and reverse mappings for model 1
m1.obj_to_cuid = generate_cuid_names(m1)
m1.cuid_to_obj = dict((cuid, obj) for obj, cuid in m1.obj_to_cuid.items())

# generate forward and reverse mappings for model 2
m2.obj_to_cuid = generate_cuid_names(m2)
m2.cuid_to_obj = dict((cuid, obj) for obj, cuid in m2.obj_to_cuid.items())

# load model 2 suffix solution into model 1
m1.s.update((m1.cuid_to_obj[m2.obj_to_cuid[obj]], val)
            for obj, val in m2.s.items())
```

Other than an extra dictionary lookup here and there (which is relatively fast in Python), the only slow part of this should be the initial generation of the ComponentUID strings, but it's only an upfront cost.

I also use this approach for long-term storage of other solution information, or when transferring solution information to a related model over the wire.

Keep in mind that the `generate_cuid_names` function generates CUID strings at the block-local context by default. Meaning if you call it on a sub-block of a model, the parent block identifier will not appear in the string. This can be useful in certain situations, but there is also a keyword for that function that will allow you to update an existing `ComponentMap` (that is assumed to include the parent block identifier). In that case, the fully-qualified CUID strings would be generated. See the doc string in pyomo/core/base/block.py for more info.